# How can I call a method of one class to another class in android

Tags: android-studio

**How can I call an acitivty DisplayContact's Method in another class?**

`DisplayContacts displayContacts = new DisplayContacts();

displayContacts.getLocation();

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Is there a method called "getLocation()" in the class DisplayContacts?  Perhaps if you copy the code in the class that would help.

Comment: Yes, DisplayContacts is a class and in that there is a method that I want to call in another  class, So that it helps me to not rewrite the same code again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to create a static class (singleton) or initialize a class with iDisposable.

```
public class DisplayContacts : IDisposable
{
    public location getLocation()
    {
        ..do stuff
        return location;
    }
}


public class myReader
{
    DisplayContacts dc = new DisplayContacts();
    location lc = dc.getLocation();
}
```

That would create a new instance of DisplayContacts then load the location in the other class.

You can use a singleton using static (declare the class and method as type static), but I only use those for application state control.  That would give you direct access to the method in the other class.

Also, make sure you are "using" the class file in the header of myReader;